# Java Application creates ZipFile with only conjunctions

Tags: java, file

I am trying to write an application in java that can pack a folder to a zip file. the user have to choose the folder with JFileChooser. When i try to pack it, it just creates a zip package with a conjunction to the folder that it should be. please can you tell me why and how to fix it?

LOLZ funny programming community, i just had to add `"\\"` instead of `"/"` while get the prefix length..

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Zipper { 

int prefixLength;
  ZipOutputStream zipOut;
  byte[] ioBuffer = new byte[4096];

  public Zipper(String dirFileName, String dirFileOutput) throws Exception
  { 
    prefixLength = dirFileName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dirFileOutput + ".zip"));
    createZipFrom(new File(dirFileName));
    zipOut.close();
  }

  void createZipFrom(File dir) throws Exception
  { if (dir.exists() && dir.canRead() && dir.isDirectory())
    { File[] files = dir.listFiles();
      if (files != null)
      { for (File file: files)
        { if (file.isDirectory()) 
          { createZipFrom(file);
          }
          else
          { String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filePath.substring(prefixLength)));
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(ioBuffer)) > 0) 
            { zipOut.write(ioBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            System.out.println(filePath + " added\n");
            zipOut.closeEntry();
            in.close();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

String path=chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
String dirFileName=chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

    String dirFileOutput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "packetname"); // thats working..

    System.out.println(dirFileName);
    System.out.println(dirFileOutput);

    new Zipper(dirFileName, dirFileOutput);

    System.out.println("package " + dirFileOutput + "." + ".zip created\n");

  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to find out what is going wrong?

Comment: i think i tried.. i just tried to output it to the command line. you mean that with debugging? the filenames seems correct the only thing is that the filenames are with "\" instead of "/" could that be the problem?

Comment: so what would you suggest?

Comment: What is exactly the problem? What do you mean by "ZipFile with only conjunctions"? I have sucessfuly zipped a simple folder with one nested folder with the code you've posted. Obviously the code is flawed, needs formatting and some more structuring, but otherwise runs fine for me.

Comment: umm ok thats screepy, now it works for me too.. sry i really cant tell you why.. when i had asked that question everytime i tried it it just creates an conjunction (or shortcut) linking to the root of my c drive.. sry

Comment: ok i tested it again, the files are not included!!! when you open the folder on another computer theyre not accessible, because its just conjunctions to local files on the machine where they were created. please check it again and transfer the packed file on another computer if you have another one. its not working

Answer (score 0):

I have written some utility methods using the NIO.2 File API, which makes zipping a folder easy. The library is Open Source. Maybe you find it usefull.

Tutorial: http://www.softsmithy.org/lib/0.4/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html#AddZipResourceSample

Javadoc: http://www.softsmithy.org/lib/0.4/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/index.html

Maven coordinates: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.softsmithy.lib|softsmithy-lib-core|0.4|bundle

Comment: thanks a lot but thats not the problem. i can zip it when i use direct input from console or a JDialog. it just dont work with the JFileChooser.